# Is there a way to search for text inside rows of a table with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input text box and an html table with rows of text.

**Table:**

- This is the first row of my table.
- This is the second row of my table.
- This is the third row of my table.

When I start typing in the input text box, I want the rows that do not match to disappear.

For example, if I type **second row**, I would like my table to show only this row:

- This is the `second row` of my table.

If I type **this is the**, I would like my table to show all 3 matching rows:

- `This is the` first row of my table.
- `This is the` second row of my table.
- `This is the` third row of my table.

If anyone knows of a script to do this, I would appreciate it! (javascript or jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want, and is pretty lightweight and clean:

http://www.jqueryfun.com/2010/06/14/filtering-through-table-rows-with-few-lines-of-code